# Filter dates based on Kuwait time zone in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, timezone, timezone-offset

I have the following query that aims at calculating a user deposits from the last (previous) Saturday at 00:00:00 until the end of the day (Sunday 00:00:00)

My date column (poorly called 'datetime') does not contain any timezone detail (ex: 2020-09-11 21:52:37.803). It is nevertheless based on the Latvian/Riga time zone where my server is located.

When filtering my rows based on datetime between Saturday 00:00:00 and Sunday 00:00:00, I am not taking into account the fact that I do not need to filter this date on Latvian time (server time) but on another time which is the 'Arab Standard Time' zone where my customers are located.

For today, my SQL date column time zone and the Arab Time Zone are equal ( UTC +3), but in winter the time between the zone will be different.

How can I cope with the potential time difference between these 2 time zones and be sure that despite of the latvian based time, I am always filtering based on Saturday 00:00:00 and Sunday 00:00:00 Kuwait time? Should I use `AT TIME_ZONE` or Offset the datetime to reflect the Arab Time Zone hour?

```
 SELECT 
      UserID, 
      SUM (DEPOSIT) AS deposits 
    FROM 
      (
        SELECT 
          UserID, 
          datetime, 
          CASE WHEN TranType = 'DEPOSIT' THEN AmountReal ELSE 0 END AS DEPOSIT 
        FROM 
          DataFeed 
        WHERE 
          datetime >= CAST (
            CAST (
              IIF (
                0 = DATEPART(
                  dw, 
                  GETDATE()
                ), 
                GETDATE(), 
                DATEADD(
                  d, 
                  (
                    (
                      (
                        7 + 0 - DATEPART(
                          dw, 
                          GETDATE()
                        )
                      ) % 7
                    ) -7
                  ), 
                  GETDATE()
                )
              ) AS DATE
            ) AS datetime
          ) --last saturday at 00:00 0=saturday
          AND datetime <= CAST (
            CAST (
              IIF (
                1 = DATEPART(
                  dw, 
                  GETDATE()
                ), 
                GETDATE(), 
                DATEADD(
                  d, 
                  (
                    (
                      (
                        7 + 1 - DATEPART(
                          dw, 
                          GETDATE()
                        )
                      ) % 7
                    ) -7
                  ), 
                  GETDATE()
                )
              ) AS DATE
            ) AS datetime
          ) 
      ) alltrans 
    GROUP BY 
      UserID
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to store the data in the UTC. So that, you will not have issues irrespective of the timezone.

Convert existing timestamps to UTC. As you know that time is in Latvian timezone, you an easily do conversion and store in UTC. Run all your queries in future, by converting UTC time to corresponding Arab time zone, where your customers are residing. `DateTimeOffset` datatype is not DST aware. You need to handle it accordingly in the winter time, to apply corresponding offset, while converting the datetime.

You can use TODATETIMEOFFSET to apply the conversion from UTC.

```
DECLARE @todaysDateTime datetime2;  
SET @todaysDateTime = GETUTCDATE()
SELECT TODATETIMEOFFSET (@todaysDateTime, '+03:00');
```

Comment: I cannot store the data differently since i must manage it as a read only user

Comment: Si if any time conversion it must be done on the fly

Comment: @R_life_R,As data is stored in Latvia time zone. I would suggest you to convert the incoming data to corresponding timezone and then run queries against data. I understand that data is read only for you. So, you have to handle it in your query.